# Init function is not getting called in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to make an app using kivy module in python. It involves different screens.
but for some reason the second screen does not get initialised.

```
class Some(Screen):
    def __int__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Some, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.layout = MDBoxLayout()
        self.layout.add_widget(Label(text='somEWHIoihat'))
        self.add_widget(self.layout)
        wadwaduhawuhdawudh
        return 1 + 1
```

This is the class. Here I tried returning in init function which does not give an error. I even have some random letter in there which also does not give any errors.

```
    self.second_screen = Some(name='2')
```

This is what I am trying to do. But it runs without any errors but no widgets are displayed on screen. When I added print functions in the **init** function of Some, it doesnot print anything which I think is because **init** function is not being called

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Are you sure that the `self.second_screen = Some(name='2')` line is being executed?

Comment: The init function of a Python class is named `__init__`, NOT `__int__`.